# How Do I install an Android app on Google TV?

Tags: android, google-tv

I have a Google TV developer's box from Google and I'm trying to install an Android app on the Google TV box. How do I do this?

I'm developing using Eclipse and Java.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment according to the [FAQS](http://code.google.com/tv/web/faq.html#installandroidapps) of Google TV,

> **Question: Can I install Android applications from a URL? (since there is no Android
> Market)**
>
> **Answer: Application downloads are not officially supported. Only
> pre-installed applications are
> available at present.**

So you cannot install your applications or download other applications from the Market at the moment. You can only use the already installed applications in Google TV.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways of doing it:

1. Copy your applications to dropbox, open them on your TV and install.
2. Copy your apps on the USB stick, install
3. Go to Market, some apps are available

I have done all of the above

Answer (score 2):

If you received your device through one of the developer offers that Google had in 2010, its just a regular retail box. At this time there is no OFFICIAL way of getting your own app on a Google TV device. The goal was to test your website with the device so it looks good. However given that there is a session at Google IO 2011 with the title "Building Android Apps for Google TV" [Google IO 2011 Sessions](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions.html) I would think that some form of Android SDK support is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Not true!
 YOu can do it! 
 Search for your Android MArket app on your phone, pull it and copy over your system

then,
adb connect ip:port,
adb install your app,

that's all, 
 I did it...